# set combo box width to auto fit it's longest field option text in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, combobox

How to set combo box width to auto fit it's longest field option text ?

Say, I have combo box field having width 300 ..But if from that combo there is a field option having some long text - bigger than 300px.

> I want to make my combo box width auto fit to that long field option
>   to see entire selected field option in Combo without any cutting.

Actually, I forgot there is config which do same thing for combo in extjs.

I think in ExtJS 4, combo width was getting set to auto fit for longest field option.

I don't want to do it by dynamically adding code to auto resize it.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to add any manual code..Don't give width ..

> grow : true,
>   growToLongestValue : true

Work for me in ExtJS 6 too..

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
       fieldLabel : 'Field',
       store : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'Long long long long long long long long'],
       grow : true,
       growToLongestValue : true,
       renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
```

Check Sencha Fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12jc

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do it manually; it is not available in the Ext code. Something like this:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(box) {
        var width = 0,
           metrics = new Ext.util.TextMetrics();
        box.getStore().each(function(rec) {
            var recWidth = textMetrics.getWidth(rec.get(box.displayField));
            width = Math.max(width,recWidth);
        });
        box.setWidth(width);
    }
}
```

Without any testing or warranty, but you should get an idea how to solve it.

A detailed example how to use TextMetrics can be found [in the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.util.TextMetrics).

Comment: Yes, It's possible in extjs without any manual code ...https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12jc